# VBA #Value Error in

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a bit of a headache when it comes to VBA. I had tried to search online for an answer but to no luck. I have learned Python, but VBA is a different ballpark.

```
Dim X As String

Function GRADELETTER_PM(Num_Grade As Double)
X = "A"
If Num_Grade >= 0.93 Then 'finds corresponding letter to a grade'
    X = "A"
    MsgBox X

End If
If Num_Grade >= 0.9 Then
    X = "A-"

End If
If Num_Grade >= 0.88 Then
    X = "B+"

End If
If Num_Grade >= 0.83 Then
    X = "B"

End If
If Num_Grade >= 0.8 Then
    X = "B-"

End If
If Num_Grade >= 0.78 Then
   X = "C+"

End If
If Num_Grade >= 0.73 Then
    X = "C"

End If
If Num_Grade >= 0.7 Then
X = "C-"

End If
If Num_Grade >= 0.67 Then
    X = "D+"

End If
If Num_Grade >= 0.6 Then
    X = "D"

End If
If Num_Grade < 0.6 Then

    X = "F"

End If
 End Function
```

The program is supposed to calculate a grade to its letter. IE a 93% (input) is an `"A"` (Output) while a 64% is a `"D"`. The only input is the grade. The sheet itself has multiple tables that do not aline themselves perfectly (ie, not the same Col x Row) and the formula will be used 40+ times on that one sheet when it works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although inefficient, this would have worked if the numbers were in ascending order rather than descending.

Comment: @Jeeped, well some ‘GRADELETTER_PM = X’ would still be missing

Comment: @DisplayName - Granted that but it isn't clear what is done with the globally public X in any event.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a `Select Case` statement, for example:

```
Function GRADELETTER_PM(ByVal Num_Grade As Double) As String
    Select Case Num_Grade
        Case Is >= 0.93: GRADELETTER_PM = "A"
        Case Is >= 0.9:  GRADELETTER_PM = "A-"
        Case Is >= 0.88: GRADELETTER_PM = "B+"
        Case Is >= 0.83: GRADELETTER_PM = "B"
        Case Is >= 0.8:  GRADELETTER_PM = "B-"
        Case Is >= 0.78: GRADELETTER_PM = "C+"
        Case Is >= 0.73: GRADELETTER_PM = "C"
        Case Is >= 0.7:  GRADELETTER_PM = "C-"
        Case Is >= 0.67: GRADELETTER_PM = "D+"
        Case Is >= 0.6:  GRADELETTER_PM = "D"
        Case Else:       GRADELETTER_PM = "F"
    End Select
 End Function
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/select-case-statement) is a reference.

Comment: Your code still spits out a value error... I am unfamiliar with Case is and what that does.

Comment: @BrandonMyers How are you using it?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PEdxk is where I'm trying to use it and https://imgur.com/a/oitdl is the new code that's not working still.

Comment: @BrandonMyers You have defined the function within the `Sheet1` module, and so the scope of the function will be limited to this worksheet. If you want the function to be available throughout the workbook, you should insert a module in which the code should reside.

Comment: The code is working. So let me try to break what I got so far. The GRADELETTER_PM = part assigns the output. The Case subsitutes the actual varialble. But what is the ByVal part?

Comment: Please consult Google first.